# Excel: if cell B2 contains a certain char then value of cell D2=E2 if not then D2, then I want to increment to E3 if Im at BX?

Tags: excel

I have the following table, what I am trying to do is to automatically generate the column D (highlighted in yellow below).

If the previous cell in column B (starting B2) has a bracket "(" then I want it to be equal

> =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("(";B1));E2;D1) [this equation is in D2]

the trick is as seen in the example below B3 till B17 have no "(" so its equal the previous value which is the above D, **but in B18 it sets to E18, however I want to be E3** and so on till the end. Any help?

[image]

Comment: Please state explicitly what you want to accomplish in words and then state what you would want your formula to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can just count how many cells containing brackets there have been in column B before the current row, and use that to pick up the next item in column E?

```
=INDEX(E:E,COUNTIF(B1:B$1,"*(*")+1)
```

[image]